# Neural Network Input scaling

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I trained a simple fully connected network on CIFAR-10 dataset:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3*32*32, 300, bias=False)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(300, 10, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(250, -1)
        self.x2 = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(self.x2)
        return x


def train():
    # The output of torchvision datasets are PILImage images of range [0, 1].
    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=250, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=args.bs, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

    net = Net()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.02, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001)

    for epoch in range(20):
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        for data in trainloader:
            inputs, labels = data
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        acc = 100. * correct / total
```

This network gets to ~50% test accuracy with the parameters specified, after 20 epochs.
Note that I didn't do any whitening of the inputs (no per channel mean subtraction)

Next I scaled up the model inputs by 255, by replacing `outputs = net(inputs)` with `outputs = net(inputs*255)`. After this change, the network no longer converges. I looked at the gradients and they seem to grow explosively after just a few iterations, leading to all model outputs being zero. I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Also, I tried scaling down the learning rate by 255. This helps, but the network only gets to ~43% accuracy. Again, I don't understand why this helps, and more importantly why the accuracy is still degraded compared to the original settings.

EDIT: forgot to mention that I don't use biases in this network.

EDIT2: I can recover the original accuracy if I scale down the initial weights in both layers by 255 (in addition to scaling down the learning rate). I also tried to scale down the initial weights only in the first layer, but the network had trouble learning (even when I did scale down the learning rate in both layers). Then I tried scaling down the learning rate only in the first layer - this also didn't help. Finally I tried reducing learning rate in both layer even  more (by 255*255) and this suddenly worked. This does not make sense to me - scaling down the initial weights by the same factor the inputs have been scaled up should have completely eliminated any difference from the original network, the input to the second layer is identical. At that point the learning rate should be scaled down in the first layer only, but in practice both layers need significantly lower learning rate...

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up the inputs will lead to exploding gradients because of a few observations:

1. The learning rate is common to all the weights in a given update step.
2. Hence, the same scaling factor (ie: the learning rate) is applied to a given weight's cost derivative regardless of it's magnitude, so large and small weights get updated by the same scale.
3. When the loss landscape is highly erratic, this leads to exploding gradients.(like a snowball effect, one overshot update - in say, the axis of one particular weight - causes another in the opposite direction in the next update which overshoots again and so on..)

The range of values of the pixels are 0 to 255, hence scaling the data by 255 will ensure all inputs are between 0 and 1 and hence more smooth convergence as all the gradients will be uniform with respect to the learning rate. But here you scaled the learning rate which adjusts some of the problems mentioned above but is not as effective as scaling the data itself. This reduces the learning rate hence making convergence time longer, that might be the reason why it reaches 43% at 20 epochs, maybe it needs more epochs..

Also:
CIFAR-10 is a significant step up from something like the MNIST dataset, hence, fully connected neural networks do not have the representation power needed to accurately predict these images. CNNs are the way to go for any image classification task beyond MNIST. ~50% accuracy is the max you can get with a fully connected neural network unfortunately.

Comment: Why is 0 to 1 better than 0 to 255?

Comment: Generally, each feature would have it's own range, hence scaling helps as it brings all features to a common range (and this helps convergence, as explained in point 2). Here, all the features already have the same range (0-255) . So in this case of RGB images, changing 0-255 to 0-1 isn't very effective, it seems effective in your case as scaling down the learning rate by this factor (or any large factor) ensures smaller steps in the right direction, but ultimately this model wouldn't converge well as it doesn't have the representation power needed, hence the loss landscape is erratic.

Comment: I tested the same dataset without any scaling but with a CNN and it reaches 70% accuracy comfortably. It seems to be a model issue rather than scaling in your case, and scaling learning rate just happened to allow you to converge smoothly, but not to a very low optimum..

Comment: So I think what is happening is gradients don't really explode, they are simple scaled up during backward pass when they go through large activations. Larger gradients are equivalent to larger learning rate, that's why scaling the learning rate helps. I'm still not quite sure why scaling down the initial weights helps (see my latest EDIT).